# Breeze: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'Person'. Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I have downloaded `HotTowel.Angular.Breeze` from NuGet and set it up with a breeze api controller.

I have configured the `datacontext.js` to create a new manager and have created and exposed a function to create a new entity:

```
function datacontext(emManager) {
    var manager = emManager.newManager();

    var service = {
        create: create,
        save: save
    };

    return service;

    function create(entityName) {
        return manager.createEntity(entityName);
    }

    function save() {
        return manager.saveChanges().to$q(saveSucceeded, saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded(result) {
            // Save Successful
        }

        function saveFailed(error) {
            // Save Failed
        }
    }
}
```

I then call this in my controller like so:

```
    function getNewPerson() {
        vm.person = datacontext.create(entityName);
        return vm.person;
    }
```

If I load this page directly in my browser, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'Person'. 
Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first.
```

However, if I navigate to the page after executing a Query, it loads fine and I'm able to save the new entity etc..

So my question is, where would be a good place to call `fetchMetadata`? Would it be in the `entityManagerFactory` on the `newManager` method?

```
    function newManager() {
        var mgr = new breeze.EntityManager({
            serviceName: serviceName,
            metadataStore: metadataStore
        });
        return mgr;
    }
```

### Edit

I've tried as suggested by @Rob below, but I still get the same error:

```
    function setupMetadata() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        metadataStore.fetchMetadata(serviceName).then(function () {
            deferred.resolve();
        }).fail(function (ex) {
            deferred.reject(ex);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Then I place `setupMetadata();` inside `app.run`:

```
app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$q', 'entityManagerFactory', function ($route, $rootScope, $q, emFactory) {
    // Include $route to kick start the router.
    breeze.core.extendQ($rootScope, $q);

    emFactory.setupMetadata();
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your dataservice pass is breeze and create a new metadatastore

```
        var servicePath = 'http://localhost/breeze/Blah';
        var metadataStore = new breeze.MetadataStore({
             //Configure Stuff
             //namingConvention: breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase
        });
```

Then fetch your metadata

```
        $rootScope.initialized = false;
        function setupMetadata() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            metadataStore.fetchMetadata(servicePath).then(function () {
                    $rootScope.initialized = trie;
                    deferred.resolve();
            }).fail(function (exception) {
                    deferred.reject(exception);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('SomeCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) { 
        $rootScope.$watch('initialized', function() {
            //Make initial calls
        });
}
```

I would expose this method so you can call it when you are bootstraping the app or authenticating to make sure the metadata store is loaded before you do anything else.

Comment: Rob is right. Treat metadata as you would any other application dependency. Another choice: you can [preload the metadata as a JavaScript file](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/load-metadata-script).

Comment: I'm trying as suggested and then running setupMetadata in the `app.run` method of angular but I still get the same error. I've edited my question to show this

Comment: It still seems like you are calling some webapi method(s) before fetchMetadata has returned successfully. Are you loading any controllers that make calls to your webapi on initialization?

Comment: Nope, `fetchMetadata` returns a promise, I was wonderign if it is possible to delay an angular app from running until this has been returned? If I do a console.log in app.run, that is output before any calls to the web api are called, so in theory it should work..

Comment: I updated my answer with one approach that could work for you. Instead of trying to delay angular from loading, you could add a watch in the controllers that need to wait for the metadata to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should check first metadata exist then create new person, your create method look like this.

```
function create(entityName) {
        var hasMetadata = checkMetadata(manager, serviceName);
        if (hasMetadata) {
            return manager.createEntity(entityName);
        } else {
            return getMetadata(manager, serviceName).then(createPerson);
        }            
    }

function createPerson()
{
    return manager.createEntity(entityName);
}

//Check wther Metadata is present in the given manager or not
var checkMetadata = function (manager, serviceName) {
    try {
        var result = false;
        if (manager.metadataStore.hasMetadataFor(serviceName)) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
};

//Method to get Metadata from a given entityManager and serviceName
this.getMetadata = function (manager, serviceName) {
    var store = manager.metadataStore;
    return store.fetchMetadata(serviceName);
};
```

I think it will be help you.